# ConstraintWidth_percent looks different in design tab and in practice

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to use `ConstraintWidth_percent` in my `shop_list_item.xml`, which is used inside my shopadapter. The problem I encounter is, that the design tab (how it should look like) and the in-app design (how it looks) are totally different. What am I doing wrong here?

### How it should look like

[image]

### How it looks

[image]

### Code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/mcv_product_item"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.40">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_product_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:loadImage="@{product.images[0]}"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription, HardcodedText"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_calibrate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_service_indicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_service"
                app:hideView="@{product.hasService}"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_product_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="@{product.name}"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textColor="@color/color_text_dark"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textDescriptionNormal1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/iv_product_image"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/iv_product_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_product_image"
                tools:text="TEST TITLE TO ENSURE STUFF" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_product_price"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:text="@{product.price}"
                android:textColor="@color/color_text_blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textHeadlineNormal1"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_product_name"
                tools:text="4870.00" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_euro"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/currency"
                android:textColor="@color/color_text_blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textHeadlineNormal1"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_product_price"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_product_name"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_product_price"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_product_price" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <!-- Currently not using -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.30"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.70"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I change `constraintWidth_percent` to something really high like 0.8, it works like it should (but looks weird in the design tab).

Comment: The width constraints of the `CardView` tells that you want the width to be the same as the parent, and then you used ` app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.40"` to have 40% of the parent .. this can be over-constrainted

Comment: I don't exactly got your point. Do you mean the combination `layout_width="0dp"` and `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4"`? Every tutorial I watched said I had to set the layout_width to 0dp in order to achieve the constraintwidth_percent. How can I solve it then?

Comment: Absolutely right but you also set `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` & `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` .. these two set the `cardView` width to match the parent width

Comment: I've deleted both, it changed nothing, but added "this view is not constraint horizontally"

Comment: Now it's under-constraint because you need the `CardView` width to be 40% of the parent .. but didn't tell from which point in the parent it can consume the 40% .. for instance is it from the start of the parent

Comment: I am hardcore confused. I've now added a constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" and still, it changed nothing :(. It looks fine in the design tab and shitty in the practice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227124/discussion-between-zain-and-andrew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal behavior as the design preview of Android Studio can have different screen size than your mobile set or the emulator.. You can change the design preview width/height to have similar width/height like your testing emulator/mobile and you'll notice there is no change.

You can change this form:

[image]

This can be very obvious as your `CardView` apparently takes the 40% of the `RecyclerView` item width. You can notice this will the green guidelines in below pic.

[image]

What you can do is to teak the 40% until you feel comfortable with a certain width that can fits for the cart items.

Last thing you can try the below layout for aligning the item in the middle of the `RecyclerView` item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/mcv_product_item"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4">


        <!--        Add CardView items -->


    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```